# How can I have Master store customer account access any (sub) store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, multistore, magento-2.1, customer-account

I have created a multi store webshop:

- www.domain.com/
- www.domain.com/store1
- www.domain.com/store2
- www.domain.com/store3

**Now how can I have Master store customer account access any (sub) store**. Is that possible in Magento 2.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multistore magento 2.1 sub store login do not working](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139977/multistore-magento-2-1-sub-store-login-do-not-working)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara, It doesn't make sense to close one question as a dupe of the other and also the other as a dupe of this one. Then you'll be running in circles ;) Also, if both get closed, this would indicate that both should/could be deleted and any valuable answers with it and thus at the end, there no answer anymore to this question...

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do that.

It's a setting in the admin under **Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options > Share Customer Accounts = Yes**